# ERROR #1052. Help me find the error in MySQL query

Tags: mysql, sql

[[image: table gift][[image: table donor[![table year]][2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SFflV.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aRbaE.png)

I need to find the donors that have donated over three times. This is what I have so far

```
 select DONOR.DONOR_LNAME as last_name, DONOR.DONOR_FNAME as first_name,    count(GIFT.AMOUNT)as NUM_PAYMENTS
from DONOR join GIFT on DONOR.DONOR_NO= GIFT.DONOR_NO 
group by DONOR_NO 
having count(AMOUNT) >=3
```

Comment: Invalid group by. Won't execute on newer MySQL versions (unless in compatibility mode), may return unpredictable results with older MySQL versions. 
 
The general GROUP BY rule says: If a GROUP BY clause is specified, each column reference in the SELECT list must either identify a grouping column or be the argument of a set function!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Error related to only\_full\_group\_by when executing a query in MySql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34115174/error-related-to-only-full-group-by-when-executing-a-query-in-mysql)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to specify the `Table Aliases` when you use `GROUP BY` AND `HAVING`.

Try this:

```
SELECT DONOR.DONOR_LNAME as last_name, DONOR.DONOR_FNAME as first_name, COUNT(GIFT.AMOUNT) as NUM_PAYMENTS
FROM DONOR 
INNER JOIN GIFT ON DONOR.DONOR_NO = GIFT.DONOR_NO 
GROUP BY DONOR.DONOR_NO 
HAVING COUNT(GIFT.AMOUNT) >= 3
```